# Create dummy variables in dataframe using for loop and apply lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I like to compute dummy variables based on the existing values in a dataframe and a dictionary with certain "cut off" points. I wonder whether I need to get rid of the for loop in the example below. And if so, how?

The second answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) Stackoverflow post compellingly urges to avoid looping through dataframes. In my real dataset (about 20.000 rows and 50 columns/variables) the "apply lambda" for the rows indeed performs much better than a for loop (which after a few hours still wasn't finished). Yet, the for loop for the columns doesn't really give a problem with time and it is handy to automatically name the variables.

Here is an example dataset

```
import pandas as pd
# create df
dict={'file':['a', 'b', 'c'],'t_0':[1.5, 2.5, 3.5], 't_1':[0.5, 1.5, 0]} 
df=pd.DataFrame(dict,index=['0', '1', '3'])
print(df)
# create dictionary with cut off points for dummy variable
d = dict={'t_0_cut_off':1, 't_1_cut_off':2}
print(d)
```

And here the for loop and apply lambda function which I use to compute the dummy variables.

```
for column in df.columns[-2:]:
    df[f'{column}_result']=df[f'{column}'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x> d[f'{column}_cut_off'] else 0)
df
```

The results look like this (and appear as I expect)

```
  file  t_0  t_1  t_0_result  t_1_result
0    a  1.5  0.5           1           0
1    b  2.5  1.5           1           0
3    c  3.5  0.0           1           0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.apply` is essentially a loop and can be slower than vectorized methods.  Here is a proposal without using `apply`:

First, we can rename the keys in the dictionary to match the column names in the dataframe:

```
d1 = {k.rsplit('_',2)[0]: v for k, v in d.items()}
#{'t_0': 1, 't_1': 2}
```

Next step is make a subset of your dataframe, since you are interested in second and subsequent columns; for this, use **[`df.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)**. Then, using **[`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)**, we can assign the values from the dictionary in the columns we are interested in and compare them with the original values using **[`df.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html)**, then convert the boolean value to `int` using **[`df.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)** . Finally, we can **[`df.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)** it back to the original dataframe and use `rsuffix` argument to rename the columns to add `"_result"`

```
sub_df = df.iloc[:,1:] #subsets the dataframe leaving the first column out
out = df.join(sub_df.gt(sub_df.assign(**d1)).astype(int) , rsuffix='_result')
```

---

Final code looks like:

```
d1 = {k.rsplit('_',2)[0]: v for k, v in d.items()}
sub_df = df.iloc[:,1:]
out = df.join(sub_df.gt(sub_df.assign(**d1)).astype(int) , rsuffix='_result')
print(out)

  file  t_0  t_1  t_0_result  t_1_result
0    a  1.5  0.5           1           0
1    b  2.5  1.5           1           0
3    c  3.5  0.0           1           0
```

Comment: "df.apply is essentially a loop and can be slower than vectorized methods," great, this was indeed the sort of answer I was looking for. So the solution proposed by @anky is a "vectorized methods" approach? Later I will also compare the time it takes to run both codes on my actual data.

Comment: Indeed it is, please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your solution then, Anky! You opened the door for me to the vectorized approach :) (I will report the run time later)

Answer (score 2):

The concept of **broadcasting** is very important for vectorized computation in both [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy) and [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#matching-broadcasting-behavior), in which a lower-dimentional array can be viewed as a higher-dimentional one for computation.

A direct improvement of your `apply` method is based on broadcasting of scalar values:

```
for column in df.columns[-2:]:
    df[f'{column}_result'] = (df[f'{column}'] > d[f'{column}_cut_off']).astype(int)
```

Instead of comparing row by row in Python, all comparisons are performed at once.

The solution can be further improved using broadcasting of 1D arrays:

```
col_names = [k.rstrip("_cut_off") for k in d.keys()]
df[list(d.keys())] = df[col_names].gt(list(d.values())).astype(int)
```

Side Remarks:

1. `dict` is a built-in class in Python and should not be used as user variable names.
2. The SO post you refer to provides several links related to the performance topic, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/are-for-loops-in-pandas-really-bad-when-should-i-care/54028200#54028200). You may want to read more of those.